# Divergence of the product of two sequences

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(x_n)_{n\ge 1}$ and $(y_n)_{n\ge 1}$ two real sequences such that $x_n\to +\infty$, $y_n\to 0$ and $x_n>y_n$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$. From my intuition I supose that the sequence $x_n y_n$ diverges because the sequence $x_n$ grows faster than $y_n$ tend to zero, but, how can I prove that in a more rigorously way?

Comment: Are you sure you mean $x_n>y_n$? That's trivial from the limits. And what is $a_n$ in the first line?

Comment: @GabrieleCassese Not quite true! It's only eventually true (but that's all that matters for our purposes anyway..).

Comment: @CameronWilliams you are right, I didn't notice the condition $\forall n$

Answer (score 3):

Let consider

- $x_n=n \to \infty$
- $y_n=\frac1{n^2} \to 0$

but

- $x_ny_n = \frac1n \to 0$

Answer (score 2):

It is not true.

Conside $x_n=n$ and $y_n=0$

Answer (score 2):

The product can converge to $0$, $\infty$, or anything in between. It really depends on the case. It can even be divergent: Take $x_n=n(\sin n+2)$, $y_n=\frac 1n$.

Take at look at this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form

Comment: $x_n = n·\sin n$ is not going to $+ \infty$. But $x_n = n · (2 + \sin n)$ will do.

Comment: Oops, embarrassing! @XanderHenderson  absolute value would still oscillate between $0$ and $n$.

Comment: @XanderHenderson No no, sorry! I was embarrassed by my mistake Paŭlo Ebermann pointed out.

Comment: @Milten Ah, ok!  I understand.  Still, I think that, perhaps, my joke was ill-made. This was probably not the right context for it. ;)

Comment: @XanderHenderson Haha, well it went over my head at least.